# Install non-Linux games via Steam

Tags: virtualbox, 13.04, games, steam

Is it possible to install non-Linux games on Ubuntu via Steam?

I have some games on my account and I hoped to run them via Wine. But Steam didn't let me to download them.

I've tried to use Virtual Machine with Windows on it `(VirtualBox)`, but there is a problem with drivers and I got crash shortly after starting game `(Torchlight 2)` No worries, I understand that I won't be able to play `Skyrim` that way, but I have some older games that I would love to play from time to time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VirtualBox isn't the best solution, since it requires 2 operating systems to run simultaneously, along with a game. Plus, you will often experience problems with the mouse not working properly.

There is a better solution. There's a program called PlayOnLinux, which is a frontend for Wine. 
Here's the download link: [PlayOnLinux Download](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html)
If you download it here, you will be able to get the latest version, which you don't get via the Software Center.

After that, you can install Steam via PlayOnLinux, and you will be able to install your Steam games through that, as long as you make sure it is the right Wine version.

You can check which Wine versions you have to use for your games, here: [Wine version](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&sTitle=Browse%20Applications&sOrderBy=appName&bAscending=true)

You can also browse games to install from PlayOnLinux, and you will be able to use the Steam version in some of them (I believe that Skyrim is one of those games, but I'm not sure). It's easier, because it finds the right Wine version for you, but of course, the PlayOnLinux doesn't feature all games, and you will have to find some of them yourself, and install them manually.

I did this, and most of my games work. 
Also, on the WineHQ site, you will be able to see how the games work via Wine, if there is large amount of bugs, or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use wine or something like it. I am a big fan (and advocate) of [Crossover](http://www.codeweavers.com/), I use it to play several windows only games in Linux. I play Torchlight 2 myself and it works fine.